# How can I create two related entities in different schemas using pony ORM?

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, pony

Say I have:

```
class Member(db.Entity):
    _table_ = ('public', 'member')
    full_name = Optional(str)
    salarys = Set('Salary')

class Salary(db.Entity):
    _table_ = ('pay', 'salary')
    id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
    member = Required(Member)
```

Member refers to table 'member' in schema 'public' or 'public.member'
Salary refers to table 'salary' in schema 'pay' or 'pay.salary'

When trying to insert a Salary i get:

> pony.orm.core.ERDiagramError: Interrelated entities must belong to
> same database. Entities Salary and Member belongs to different
> databases

How do I come around this issue?

Help please, I don´t seem to find this asked before, I am using postgresql